# How to get ampersand "&" in output of Transform xml activity of TIBCO

Tags: xslt, transform

Could anyone please help in getting the ampersand "&" output of Transform xml activity of TIBCO .

My requirement is the xmlstring from Transform xml activity is mapped to Parse xml (which will give the final output ) .Ex; Maitree&Sons. What should be passed in xslt so that when the output from Transform xml  goes to Parse xml it will give the final result as "&".

I tried using CDATA and disable-escaping-output also in xslt but in parse xml it fails.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Generally XSLT won't allow you to produce invalid output. The correct representation in XML is `Maitree&amp;Sons` and this is what it produces. If it produced `Maitree&Sons`, this would be invalid XML and would be thrown out by an XML parser trying to read the document.

Having said that, it's possible using `disable-output-escaping` to produce an unescaped ampersand if your XSLT processor supports this option. If it's not working for you we need to know exactly what you did and how it failed.

(General rule: on SO, always tell us exactly what you did and exactly how it failed. Saying in general terms that you tried lots of things and none of them worked doesn't get us any nearer to a solution.)

**LATER**

I'm reading the question again. You want to produce output from the transformer that will go into an XML parser, such that the output of the parser is `Maitree&Sons`. Well, in that case the lexical XML must be `Maitree&amp;Sons`, which it will be if you generate the string `Maitree&Sons` in XSLT. But XSLT is XML, so if you want to write this as a literal string in your stylesheet, it will be written `Maitree&amp;Sons`.

I guess we need a much clearer picture of what you are doing and where it is going wrong.

Comment: Thank you Michael for information . But as you suggested I had used the below in the XSLT stylesheet by assigned a string literal to a variable  <xsl:variable name="supplierName1" select="Maitree&amp;Sons"/> . It failed in Transform xml with the error  "Expecting 'END_MARKER' but found token 'UNEXPECTED'."  Kindly help me to get desired output from XML parser .

Comment: The value of the select attribute must be an expression, so it you want a literal, you need nested quotes: `select="'literal'"` (Pretty naff error message, by the way)

Comment: Hi Michael , I tried with select="'Literal'" also but got error . Could you please provide a sample example so that I could implement in my project.

Comment: If you got an error, tell us what the error is. As a developer, if I get an error, I investigate why I got it, I don't just try something else.

Comment: Hi Michael sorry for late response . Please check for the error below .The [javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException] occurred during XSLT transformation:  javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException:The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.  This is the error I got when I tried with string literal. Let me know how can I achieve the end result (Maitree&Sons)

Comment: That suggests that your literal contains an `&` which you haven't escaped as `&amp;`.